# PHP save disabled input into database

Tags: php, html

Hi is there a way to save disabled input in your database?

Like this below

```
< input type="text" disabled name="item_name" >
```

the disabled there has a useful function in my case since i show the input box but I wont allow user to change it

but when I use query to save this input  box it says 'undefine item_name'
my suspect is that disabling input will not allow data to capture by php and insert to your database

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO items values('$item_name')");
```

Comment: why disabled, why not readonly, its more or less same, user wont be able to edit or enter anything in readonly input too `< input type="text" readonly name="item_name" >`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabled inputs are not submitted. For your requirement, use readonly attribute. User won't be able to change it but it will be submitted.

```
readonly="readonly"
```

Comment: you stole my answer bro, how are you and how was eid

Comment: @shehary bad timing I would say :p

Comment: @shehary I'm fine, thanks. Eid went well, now back to work ;-)

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano, mark it answer, or i will post the answer too :D

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan, great, will catch you later, will give you a call :)

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano sure. Why do you want to post this field anyway? If the purpose of this field is just to display your text, then just print it as is without any input tag.

Comment: @shehary sure bro. See ya! :)

Comment: @Raja Amer Khan - if ordinary user account will log-in input box is disabled for editing but if admin will log-in then I allow it for editing .. :)
but I remove the border for user to appear like an ordinary text

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano then simply add an if else statement, and do not create input tag for ordinary user. e.g. if($_SESSION['user_type']=='admin') { echo "<input name='user_type' value='$user_details->type'>"; } else { echo $user_details->type; }

Answer (score 2):

Disabled fields are not posted.

By disabling the field, you mean you need to have to field in the form.

Also, you are not allowing the field to be edited.

You can do one thing:

Add a hidden field with the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $YOUR_VALUE;?>"/>
```

And add text which shows its value e.g. `<?php echo $item_name;?>`

Thus, you will have the value of the fields shown on the form also, you are posting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session` because disabled inputs are not submitted
`session_start();`

```
$_SESSION['$item_name'] = $item_name;

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO items values('$_SESSION['$item_name']')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use readonly

```
<input type="text" name="item_name" readonly>
```